# SELECT MAX(... not returning anything in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, max

This is the table structure-

```
Table: test

+------+---------+
| PAGE | CONTENT |
+------+---------+
|  1   |   ABC   |
+------+---------+
|  2   |   DEF   |
+------+---------+
|  3   |   GHI   |
+------+---------+
```

`PAGE` is a Primary with datatype `INT(11)`. It does not auto-increment.  CONTENT is of the datatype `TEXT`.

In PHP I do-

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT MAX(PAGE) FROM test);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["PAGE"];
```

No output. At all. If I do something like `echo "Value : ".$row["PAGE"];` all I see is `Value :`

The query `SELECT * FROM test` works just fine though. Am I wrong somewhere using the `MAX()` syntax?

I want it to return the maximum value of `PAGE` as of yet.

Comment: Everything seems all right..could you try using this query `SELECT MAX(PAGE) as PAGE FROM test` instead and see if theres any difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Been struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should be the code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(PAGE) AS max_page FROM test");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["max_page"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you have quotes around that query in `mysql_query`? I have no idea what PHP will do with such a syntactically inadequate statement, I would have thought it would have given you an error.

In any case, an aggregate function may have a different column name than the column used for it (from memory, DB2 gives it a similar name to the function, like `max_page_` or something). You may want to ensure it has the correct column name by forcing the name with something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(PAGE) AS MAXPAGE FROM TEST");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["MAXPAGE"];
```

Comment: I think he just mistyped it, as he'd be getting an error not just nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT max(page2_content_id) AS max_page from page2_content_data");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["max_page"];
```

Where `$con=new mysqli($server,$user,$password,$db_name);` and *page2_content_data* is my table,and *page2_content_id* is the column name

Comment: Users of SO can order answers in several ways, so speaking of *"above answer and below"* is mostly meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "carBid") or die("not connected");

//connection to database
$sql2 = "SELECT max(mybid) FROM `bid`";

//simle select statement with max function
$result_set2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

//query a result fetch
if ($result_set2) {
    $rowB = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set2);
    //feching a result in array format
    echo $rowB['max(mybid)'];
    //accessing array by name of column with max() function of mysql
} else {
    echo 'No Current Bid';
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: There is one "{" too much or too less, I think.

Comment: Just a quick note. `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` are deprecated.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: <?php

$connect=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "carBid") or
        die("not connected");
 //connection to database

$sql2 = "SELECT max(mybid) FROM `bid`";
//simle select statement with max function
$result_set2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
//query a result fetch
if ($result_set2) {
    $rowB = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set2);
//feching a result in array format
    echo $rowB['max(mybid)'];
    
    //accessing array by name of column with max() function of mysql
} else {
    echo 'No Current Bid';
}


mysqli_close($connect);

?>

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this in my code;

```
$maxscore_query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(`score`) FROM `allscores` WHERE`level`='$levelcode'");

echo mysql_result($maxscore_query, 0);
```

The difference here is the use of WHERE for selecting a group.

And `mysql_result($maxscore_query, 0);` is easier to manage for me.