# how to get max value of a sql database query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find out the max value of sql data column on the basis of email id and username. (there is no primary entity)
To get the email id, i store the user email id from session.

here goes my code:

```
$emailid = $userRow['emailid'];

$sql = "select max(item) from product where email = '$emailid' AND username = 'arun'";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "Max item : " .$row['result'];
```

It's giving me first value of sql table but not highest.

Comment: What data type is item in the database?

Comment: bro item is INT type

Comment: `"SELECT MAX(item) AS result  FROM product WHERE email = '$emailid' AND username = 'arun'"`   try this

Comment: `$sql = "select item from product where email = '$emailid' AND username = 'arun' order by item desc limit 1";` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT MAX(... not returning anything in PHP/MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435342/select-max-not-returning-anything-in-php-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either change your column data-type or use `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX( CAST( `item` AS UNSIGNED) ) as max FROM `product` WHERE `email` = '$emailid' AND `username` = 'arun'";
```

**If possible its better to change the data-type.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$emailid = $userRow['emailid'];
$sql = "SELECT MAX(item) AS item FROM product WHERE email = '$emailid' AND username = 'arun'";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "Max item : " .$row['item'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$rowSQL = mysql_query( "SELECT MAX( ID ) AS max FROM `tableName`;" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $rowSQL );
$largestNumber = $row['max'];
```